# Maximum singular value via nonconvex QCQP

Tags: optimization, reference-request, svd, singular-values, qcqp

Finding the extremal singular triplet $(σ, u, v)$ of a generic real $m×n$ matrix $A$ can be formalized as a nonconvex [quadratically-constrained quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) (QCQP):

$$σ = \max_{u,v}\quad  u^⊤ A v \qquad\text{s.t.}\qquad ‖u‖_2 = 1 \text{ and } ‖v‖_2 =1$$

Or, in standard form: $\max\limits_{z} \frac{1}{2} z^⊤ Q z$  with $z^⊤P_kz + ρ_k = 0$ for $k=1…K$.

$$ σ = \max_{u,v}\quad
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix}^⊤\!\! ⋅
\begin{bmatrix}  & A \\  A^⊤ &  \end{bmatrix}
⋅\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\text{s.t.}\qquad
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix}^⊤\!\! ⋅
\begin{bmatrix}  &  \\   &  \end{bmatrix}
⋅\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix} &= 1
\\
\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix}^⊤\!\! ⋅
\begin{bmatrix}  &  \\   &  \end{bmatrix}
⋅\begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix} &= 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Which can be classified/summarized as QCQP with the properties:

- $Q$ symmetric (but not necessarily positive definite!)
- $P_k$ symmetric positive semi-definite.
- The feasible set is compact, hence a global optimum exists
- Some block/sparsity structure

Additionally, this can be classified as a [**biconvex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconvex_optimization) problem and [**bilinear program**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_program).

---

**Questions:**

- What does standard optimization theory have to say about this problem? General QCQPs are NP-hard, but apparently some classes of QCQP can be relaxed towards SDP or even SOCP problems.
- What are effective, off-the-shelve algorithms for solving such problems? Can we recover methods like the [alternating power iteration](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=B1QRgziT-)? Are there modified Newton Methods with quadratic convergence?

**References:**

- https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande311/lecture15.pdf Constructs a SDP relaxation and claims exactness.
- Multiple works construct unconstrained proxies that are optimized via gradient descent [[Hasan 2008]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4518014), [[Feng 2017]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231217310615), [[Xu 2019]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8996452), [[Feng 2021]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11063-021-10522-w)

Comment: You may want to take a look at chapter 3 of Helmke & Moore's [Optimization and Dynamical Systems](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF) [PDF]

Comment: These two articles seem relevant:

- [Solving pooling problems with time discretization by LP and
SOCP relaxations and rescheduling methods](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-019-00795-w)
- [Exact SDP relaxations for quadratic programs with bipartite graph structures](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-022-01268-3)

as they discuss relaxations of the QCQP under certain sparsity structures.

Comment: Take a look at [Optimization Algorithms on
Matrix Manifolds](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Optimization%20Algorithms%20on%20Matrix%20Manifolds%20%5BAbsil%2C%20Mahony%20%26%20Sepulchre%202007-12-23%5D.pdf), I think the book covers even more general problems there.